# The URI Online Judge won't accept my answer

Tags: java, exception, runtime, uri

Question link here https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1030

I'm trying to submit the answer to this question but all I get are runtime errors. It says that this is because an array index (or similar) error, but I don't think that's the case here, since I'm using ArrayLists and the output is correct on my computer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    static class Pair {

        public int size;
        public int step;

        public Pair(int l, int r) {
            size = l;
            step = r;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int tests = s.nextInt();
        int[] res = new int[tests];
        Pair[] inputs = new Pair[tests];

        // take input first
        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
            inputs[i] = new Pair(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());


        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {


            final int step = inputs[i].step;
            int size = inputs[i].size;
            int pos = step;

            ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int c = 0; c < inputs[i].size; c++)
                nums.add(new Integer(c));

            if (size == 1) {
                res[i] = nums.get(0);
                continue;
            }


            while (size > 1) {

                nums.remove(pos);
                size--;
                pos--;
                pos = pos + step;
                if (pos >= size)
                    pos = pos % size;

            }

            res[i] = nums.get(0);

        }
        int count = 1;
        for (int i : res) {

            System.out.println("Case " + count++ + ": " + i);
        }
    }
```

}

The outputs I get on IntelliJ IDEA are just like the ones in the example, so I believe this solution does what it should.

Comment: Hi ZappSnapp.  Can you include the stack trace with the errors to help people debug?  If you are claiming the output looks the same as expected but it's still throwing an error it is very hard for us to help.